# How do I handle errors for get API request

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I have written an API to view logs of my server in browser. I tried but not getting how to do error handling. Please show how will you do error handling. I am new to node.js

```
app.get('/logs', function(request, response, next) {
res.sendFile('file', 'path');
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show?

Comment: What's the error that you're trying to handle?

Comment: I have tried try catch block. I didnt get any error for now but to avoid any error in future, I want to do error handling

Comment: @RohanMandhare: *"I have tried try catch block"* - Not in the code you're showing you haven't.  *"I didnt get any error"* - That would explain why your error handling didn't do anything then.  It's still not clear what the actual problem is here.

Comment: @David I am new to node.js and dont know error handling I tried from few tutorials but didnt get it. Thats why I asked question, if you know the answer you're appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Error handling looks something like this below.

```
app.get('/logs', async function(req, res) {
  let something;
  try {
    something = await "file processing";
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ error: error.toString() });
  }
  res.json({ something });
});
```

when you are fetching API from other endpoint, you can use `promise` or `async-await`

when something goes wrong in the `try` statement, then error will be catched

if you want to make error deliberately, using `new Error()` in `try` statement

you can also study express error middleware when trying to handle route errors.